# Eclipse could not detect what state and target my VM is on Android x86

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, x86, adb

I have followed many instructions online to start working an Android VM. Everything worked perfectly for the VM but on Eclipse I encountered a problem, I did the connections and port forwarded via VirtualBox but whenever I click run or debug on Eclipse it shows `Android Device Chooser` but it shows the VM loaded as this:

[image]

Information:

- Virtual Machine:
- Adapter:

  - Adapter Attached To: NAT
  - Adapter Type: PCnet-FAST III (Am79c973)
  - Port Forward: TCP & UDP : 5555
- ISO: android-x86-4.0-RC2-eeepc.iso

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2604727/995891 ,that should apply to your scenario. Or maybe just a reboot of the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Close the VM. In eclipse go to window->avd manager->select EDIT on your vm->select the target->save.

Then run your project and if your projects minsdk fits with that VMs target level it will launch.

Comment: The AVD Manager you told me to go to is only for the VM that is created within Eclipse so I couldn't get the VM in the dialog.